# my htaccess file doesn't redirect subpages

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect  www.site.org/state/ohio.html  to www.site.org/
I need any subpages of the folder state, to just redirect to the main site index page.
i can't get that to work.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?state/(.+)$ www.example.com
```

this is still keeping it site.org/ohio.html
I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the rule is in the htaccess file in your document root. If there are redirects already in there, you may need to take a look at the order of the directives.

Then you just need to redirect to `/`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?state/(.+)$ /
```

Comment: you mention order of directives. What difference does the order make?

Comment: @user1899829 if you're using regular expressions, you want the more exclusive patterns to be first. For example. a `RedirectMatch ^/foo/bar/1234/(.*)$` needs to be **before** a `RedirectMatch ^/foo/bar/(.*)$` because the second regex would match everything the first one does. If the order were swapped, the regex with the "1234" would never fire off.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just missing http:// before url

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?state/(.+)$ http://www.example.com
```